# Promise within a promise for Express Router call - React - Redux

Tags: express, promise, react-redux

I'm having difficulties with chaining my api calls together so that one doesn't finish before the other.

I'd like to query from the first api all of the accounts specified to a user, then I'd like to take the array of accounts returned and query their account balances from another database. Finally, add the balances to their account object, and res.json( array of accounts).

The problem I'm having is that the query that finds the accounts isn't waiting for the query that adds the balances in to finish, and all the balances are sent to my state as undefined. I found this out using console.log() throughout the two queries ( not shown below ).

I'm relatively new to promises from api calls so I'm not sure what is the best way to go about it. I haven't had any luck with the .all notation for promises that I have below, I'm not sure if that's the best way to go about it since there can be multiple accounts returned from the first API call.

Here is the first API call that queries the Accounts.

```
router.get(
  "/accounts",
  passport.authenticate("jwt", { session: false }),
  (req, res) => {
    Account.find({ userId: req.user.id })
      .then(accounts => {
        return accounts.map((account) => addBalanceToAccount(account));
      }).all( (ret) => {
          // NOT SURE WHAT TO DO HERE
          ret.then((value) => console.log(value));
          res.json(ret)
      })
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
  }
);
```

The second api call is in the addBalanceToAccount(account) function. 
Basically I use the ACCESS_TOKEN to query the database. 
An ACCESS_TOKEN can be tied to multiple accounts so that's why I filter them to just the account that matches the account ID.

Sometimes a Bank will return an error object instead of the balance, so in that case value === undefined will result.

My idea with this function is to return a promise i.e. the return client, then have the annoymous function within the promise return the new account object with the balance added.

```
function addBalanceToAccount(account){
  ACCESS_TOKEN = account.accessToken;
  let value;
  let accountFound;

  return client
    .getBalance(ACCESS_TOKEN)
    .then(response => {
        accountFound = response.accounts.filter((a) => a.account_id === account.accountId);
        value = accountFound.length > 0 ? accountFound[0].balances.current : -2;
        return value === undefined ? {...account, balance: -1} : {...account, balance: value}
    })
    .catch(err => {console.log("ERROR"); return {...account, balance: -3};});
}
```

This is my train of thought...

the return accounts.map() should return an array of Promises, that's why I use the .all(). Then in the .all() I should be able to wait for all of the accounts to query their balances. In the end res.json() should return an array of account objects that have a key {balance: value} in them

Answer (score 0):

Found a way to get it to work. Just had to tweak up my .all() call :)

```
router.get(
  "/accounts",
  passport.authenticate("jwt", { session: false }),
  (req, res) => {
    Account.find({ userId: req.user.id })
      .then(accounts => {
        Promise.all(accounts.map((account) => addBalanceToAccount(account)))
          .then((accountList) => res.json(accountList))
      })
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
  }
);
```